# How to reload Visible cells of TableView in ios swift

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to change font size after the cell is loaded with data. On click of the icon of the tabbar i show an alertcontroller action sheet.
On click of one of the actions i want to change the font size of the labels in the cells.

[image]

[image]

The code i am using is below:

```
 //Two global variables,retaining size of each labels
 var fontSizeWord = 20.0
 var fontSizeMeaning = 12.0

 func changeFont(){
        let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Change Font", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        optionMenu.view.tintColor = UIColor(red: 179/256, green: 180/256, blue: 255/256, alpha: 1.0)
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel)
        let smallfont = UIAlertAction(title: "Small", style: .default) { (UIAlertAction) in
            self.fontSizeMeaning = 12
            self.fontSizeWord = 20
            self.reloadData()
        }
        let mediumfont = UIAlertAction(title: "Medium", style: .default) { (UIAlertAction) in
            self.fontSizeMeaning = 15
            self.fontSizeWord = 23
            self.reloadData()
        }
        let largefont = UIAlertAction(title: "Large", style: .default) { (UIAlertAction) in
            self.fontSizeMeaning = 18
            self.fontSizeWord = 26
            self.reloadData()
        }
        let extraLarge = UIAlertAction(title: "Extra Large", style: .default) { (UIAlertAction) in
            self.fontSizeMeaning = 21
            self.fontSizeWord = 29
            self.reloadData()
        }
        optionMenu.addAction(cancelAction)
        optionMenu.addAction(smallfont)
        optionMenu.addAction(mediumfont)
        optionMenu.addAction(largefont)
        optionMenu.addAction(extraLarge)
        self.present(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:SearchTableViewCell = self.searchTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! SearchTableViewCell
        cell.wordLbl.font = cell.wordLbl.font.withSize(CGFloat(fontSizeWord))
        cell.meaningLbl.font = cell.meaningLbl.font.withSize(CGFloat(fontSizeMeaning))
        return cell
    }
```

My problem is the font of visible cells only changes once i scroll a little bit. How can i fix it to change as the action of uiactionsheet is triggered.

Comment: Show code of reload data and cell for row method

Comment: Does reloading the entire tableView work?

Comment: Koh no man its not working

Comment: tableView.reloadRows(at: tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows!, with: .automatic)

Comment: Abu UI Hassan Thanks mate this one instruction worked like a charm.

Comment: Although now there is a blur problem.

Comment: From a Human Interface Guidelines point of view, it is better if your app adopts dynamic type rather than implementing its own font size preference.  This way your app will automatically adapt to the user's font size preferences.

Comment: Thanks Paulw11 unfortunately the font i am using is not dynamic font.

Comment: I will make sure to keep that in mind for future purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this Snippet

```
self.searchTableView.reloadRows(at: self.searchTableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows!, with: .automatic)
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the indexPath for the visible rows you can use this:

```
let indexPathsForVisibleRows = yourTableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows
```

Then you can reload those specific cells using:

```
yourTableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPathsForVisibleRows], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
```

Comment: "Cannot invoke 'indexPathsForVisibleRows' with no arguments" getting this on first instruction.

Comment: @CaptionNewt and anyone who may see this. You have to use indexPathsForVisibleRows like this now: `tableView.reloadRows(at: tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows!, with: .none)` and if you don't like to force unwrap:                                                                                                                  
   `if let indexPathsForVisibleRows = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows {
                tableView.reloadRows(at: indexPathsForVisibleRows, with: .automatic)
            }`

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have to call `reloadData` from the main thread:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

If this does not work your issue must be somewhere else. Compare your project with my solution:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    enum FontSize: String, CaseIterable {
        case small = "Small"
        case medium = "Medium"
        case large = "Large"

        var pointSize: CGFloat {
            switch self {
            case .small: return 10
            case .medium: return 20
            case .large: return 30
            }
        }
    }

    var currentFontSize: FontSize = .medium {
        didSet {
            if currentFontSize != oldValue, let indexPathsForVisibleRows = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows {
                tableView.reloadRows(at: indexPathsForVisibleRows, with: .automatic)
            }
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 100
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: currentFontSize.pointSize)
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Font Size", message: "Choose your preferred font size.", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        let handler: (UIAlertAction) -> Void = { alert in
            guard let title = alert.title, let fontSize = FontSize(rawValue: title) else { return }
            self.currentFontSize = fontSize
        }

        for fontSize in FontSize.allCases {
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: fontSize.rawValue, style: .default, handler: handler))
        }
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

        present(alert, animated: true)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create some methods,this is how I did.

```
func configureVisibleCells(for tableView: UITableView?, animated: Bool) {
    self.tableView(tableView, configureRowsAtIndexPaths: tableView?.indexPathsForVisibleRows, animated: animated)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView?, configureRowsAtIndexPaths indexPaths: [Any]?, animated: Bool) {
    for indexPath in indexPaths as? [IndexPath] ?? [] {
        let cell: UITableViewCell? = tableView?.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
        if cell != nil {
            self.tableView(tableView, configureCell: cell, forRowAt: indexPath, animated: animated)
        }
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView?, configureCell cell: UITableViewCell?, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath?, animated: Bool) {
    // Cell configuration
}
```

Configure the Cell in the `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView?, configureCell cell: UITableViewCell?, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath?, animated: Bool)`  method and call this method in your `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` .

and when you need to reload visible cells call the method `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

Hope this may help you.